# Como usar letras ao invés de números dentro do vetor LETTERS?

Tags: r

O vetor `LETTERS` funciona da seguinte forma:

```
LETTERS[1:10]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

Como **ajustar** este vetor para inserir letras ao invés de números? Algo como:

```
LETTERS[A:J]
Error: object 'A' not found
```

Isso evitaria ter de contar as letras do alfabeto para especificar o intervalo de caracteres desejado.

Comment: `LETTERS` é um vetor (objeto), não uma função

Comment: Corrigido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma opção (longa) seria:

```
LETTERS[which("A" == LETTERS):which("J" == LETTERS)]
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

Dentro de uma função:

```
lettersSeq = function(primeira, segunda) {
  return(LETTERS[which(primeira == LETTERS):which(segunda == LETTERS)])
}

lettersSeq("A", "J")
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```